# Create one record per day for records under a certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out how to record the Status of each unique ID in one of my tables so I can get historical data for each status. I want to be able to then count per day or month how many Unique ID's were in a certain status, so it's essentially I think a table that adds the unique ID with the Status at the time and a time stamp every day. I want this as a view so I can then connect to PowerBI for data analysis.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to or where to start.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you need an audit table or need to enable cdc

Comment: Agree with Doug, audit table would help you to store the historical data with timestamp. Also that would be a good way when you need do backups. When you create a normal table and it's audit table, add triggers on normal table. So that when another records inserted or updated, they would be reflected to the audit table.

Comment: I think i didnt explain myself properly, the record will have no updates or changes in 1 month or more, but I want to have a record per day for each day that record met a certain condition. For example, Record1 was on my table for 3 months, it had an update on month 2, but I want to have a table with a record for each DAY the record was present on the database even though it might not have had any changes.